# Extension to the @ syntax

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, comments

When replying in comments using the @ symbol sometimes it may useful to reply to a group in general.

I am specifically thinking about when a question is closed. You may want to write a comment that gets flagged to all the closers. But there could be other pseudo group flags that could be used under certain conditions.

Suggestions:

- @Closers
- @Commenters
- @Admin

Comment: This isn't a duplicate; I like `@Closers` and am completely opposed to `@Downvoters` (I don't see the use case for `@Commenters`, but maybe there is one)

Comment: Closers can't remove their close vote, so what good would this do?

Answer (score 13):

> @Admin

I think this one would be more complicated than it was worth.  If you *really* need to, you can flag. Who would this even notify?  Pick a mod at random?  Notify ALL the mods?(!)

> @Commenters

I can't think of a use case for this.  If two people said the same thing (first of all why didn't the second guy just upvote the first?), you can respond to them without having to bug *everyone* who's commented on the question.  I can see this generating a lot of inbox spam as people who drop comments like:

> Don't forget to frob the woodget!

are getting notified by the guy responding to a different commenter who said:

> But Microsoft is *better* than Apple!

Because really, if we implemented this, how many people do you think would use it the way it was intended?  I can see it being far easier to remember `@Commenters` than having to, you know, remember peoples *names*.

> @Closers

No.  Please no.  I vote to close a fair deal on the sites I can, and on SO especially, I see many comments like:

> @Closer why you close quesiton???? my qeustion is good u are terrble for not understanding it.

Usually they're not that nice, but I think you get the point.  This would generate more inbox spam, but directed more at the user directly and not in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I do like the idea of @Closers and @Commenters, and for that I +1'd.

In spite if that, I do not support @Admin - there's already the "flag" functionality for that purpose.